# AS returns Invalid <color> for given resource value

Tags: android, css

My Android Studio is returning the following error:

E:\Android\OdontoApp\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:10:4: Invalid  for given resource value.

The colors.xml file is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>

    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>

    <color name="navy_blue">#2039DA</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#0C1B77</color>

    <color name="transparent">#00000</color>
</resources>
```

The line with the error in question is the "black" color line, but I can't figure what is wrong with it. Can someone help?

Already remade the whole file to try fix it, but no success, the same error on the same line appeared again.

SOLVED: Had to change to "transparent" hex code to #00FFFFFF

Comment: Can't you have it possibly defined somewhere else? What does the Android studio tell you when you hover over it?(the red lines)

Comment: That's the thing, the file itself shows no errors, only on the log when I try building the APK, it returns "Invalid <color> for given resource value." I'll try checking around the xmls to check if I mispelled something when I was building the layouts.

Comment: Hey @phobos445 could you upvote my answer in addition to marking it correct if you come back to this? Thanks, glad it’s working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transparent as `#00000` is not valid, instead use: `#00FFFFFF`.

I reproduced the error locally and this resolved it.

The problem is that there are 2 channels for 3 colors and you only provided 5 digits.

There are an additional 2 channels at the beginning for the alpha, so the key is to give a 8 digit code starting with 00s for the alpha channel.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Thanks for the answer, the code returned some other errors, but I managed to fix them quickly, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: For sure! That was a really tricky one. (Would love an up vote as well by the way :D)

Comment: tried giving you an up vote but I don't have enough rep yet :/